# Problem with Schur’s lemma for algebraically closed fields

Tags: linear-algebra, representation-theory

##### A corollary of Schur’s lemma states that:

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional irreducible representation of an algebra $A$ over an algebraically closed field $k$, and let $φ \colon V \to V$ be an intertwining operator. Then $φ = λ \cdot \mathrm{Id}$ for some $λ ∈ k$ (a scalar operator).

##### Consider this proof:

Let $λ$ be an eigenvalue of $φ$ (a root of the characteristic polynomial of $φ$). It exists since $k$ is an algebraically closed field. Then the operator $φ − λ \cdot \mathrm{Id}$ is an intertwining operator $V \to V$, which is not an isomorphism (since its determinant is zero). Thus by Schur’s lemma this operator is zero, hence the result.

##### My problem is:

The proof above implies that $φ = λ \cdot \mathrm{Id}$ for any eigenvalue $λ$. So if $φ$ has multiple distinct eigenvalues, how could $φ$ be equal to a number of different scalar maps?

Comment: Your problem doesn't arise, because then such a $\phi$ is not an intertwining operator. It can only be a fixed multiple of the identity.

Comment: So for any intertwining operator $\phi$, the characteristic polynomial has at most $1$ distinct zero?

Comment: What do you know about the degree of the characteristic polynomial? Try the identity matrix $I_n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A corollary of the corollary is that $φ$ cannot have multiple distinct eigenvalues.

Comment: Thank you. Do you have an example of such a $\phi$ that has only repeated eigenvalues?

Comment: You can take $φ = λ \cdot \mathrm{Id}$. The corollary tells us that these are the only possible choices.